# Weird indent on li marker in Safari, iPad (and assuming iPhone)

Tags: css, html-lists

Here is a visual of what is happening, since I am not great at describing this in words:

[image]

You can also see this in action by clicking [here](http://www.freshmarketstores.com/departments/produce/produceGlossary.php).

Also, this behavior is not exhibited when you click on one of the recipes (the same list is generated on that page too, with the same css stylings), so I am stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two floated elements above the list are causing that. You could just add `clear: both`:

```
.recipeList {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much for this. I totally should have thought about it, I even tried to add padding to the top of the UL element, but it didn't help so I stopped thinking about the recipeList elements causing the problem. Thanks again!